# Python: How to count all objects in an array that match a condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How can I count all objects in an array that match a condition: `is_read == true`?

This is how my array looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "is_read": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "is_read": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "is_read": false,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "is_read": true,
  },
]
```

Comment: `arr.filter( el => el.is_read ).length`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just use `filter` method by passing a `callback` function and use `length` property applied for the result of filtering.

```js
let data = [ { "id": 1, "is_read": true, }, { "id": 2, "is_read": true, }, { "id": 3, "is_read": false, }, { "id": 4, "is_read": true, }, ],
length = data.filter(function(item){
  return item.is_read;
}).length;
console.log(length);
```

You can also use a `lambda` expression.

```js
 let data = [ { "id": 1, "is_read": true, }, { "id": 2, "is_read": true, }, { "id": 3, "is_read": false, }, { "id": 4, "is_read": true, }, ],
length = data.filter(d => d.is_read).length;
console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 9):

**Filter**

```js
const count = (arr, condition) => arr.filter(condition).length;

const arr = [ { is_read: true }, { is_read: false} ]
console.log(count(arr, (o) => o.is_read));
```

**Array#reduce**

```js
const count = (arr, condition) => arr.reduce((acc, c) => condition(c) ? ++acc : acc, 0);

const arr = [ { is_read: true }, { is_read: false } ]
console.log(count(arr, (o) => o.is_read));
```

**Recursive**

```js
const count = ([first, ...rest], condition, acc = 0) => 
           (condition(first) && ++acc, 
           rest.length ? count(rest, condition, acc) : acc);

const arr = [ { is_read: true }, { is_read: false } ]
console.log(count(arr, (o) => o.is_read));
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Array.reduce

```
const r = (sum, obj) => sum + (obj.is_read == true ? 1 : 0);
const count = arr.reduce(r, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Comment: you're welcome @FeedGit. You can omit the (obj.is_read == true ? 1 : 0) part if you can be certain that obj.is_read is always a boolean. Then it will be reduced to const r = (sum, obj) => sum + obj.is_read;

Comment: Yeah. Appreciated it! :)

Answer (score 4):

Use array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
//ES6
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "is_read": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "is_read": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "is_read": false,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "is_read": true,
  },
]

const size = arr.filter(obj => obj.is_read).length
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), starting from `0` and adding the result of the predicate for each element. This works because `true` can be coerced to `1` and `false` to `0`.

```js
const getMatchCount = (arr, predicate)=>arr.reduce((a,b)=>a + predicate(b), 0);

console.log(getMatchCount([{ "id": 1, "is_read": true, }, { "id": 2, "is_read": true, }, { "id": 3, "is_read": false, }, { "id": 4, "is_read": true, }], 
  x => x.is_read));
// get number of objects in the array whose "is_read" property is true

console.log(getMatchCount([1, 2, 3, 6, 13, -2, 9, 9], 
  x => x % 2 === 1));
// get number of odd numbers in array
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, but turned into a TypeScript function:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "is_read": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "is_read": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "is_read": false,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "is_read": true,
  },
]

function arrayCount<T>(arr: T[], predicate: (elem: T, idx: number) => boolean) {
    return arr.reduce((prev, curr, idx) => prev + (predicate(curr, idx) ? 1 : 0), 0)
}

console.log(arrayCount(arr, x => x.is_read))  // 3
```